# SSRS Subscription error: Message size exceeds fixed maximum but also doesn't

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscription

I have a subscription that has been setup for a long time. It sends an attachment that is approx **11mb** in size to an email distribution list. The original subscription runs fine, but when I try create a new subscription on the same report, sending the report as an attachment I get the error message:

> *Failure sending mail: Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message
> sizeMail will not be resent.*

I have checked the Database mail properties and the attachment limit is **30mb**. I've also checked the SMTP server attachment limit and this is set to **50mb**. I attached a screen shot of the subscriptions to show how one is working and one is not. (the first one is the new subscription that failed, the 3rd row is the one that sends out every day, the other 2 are file shares) The new sub is a day out, but that's because I stopped the new subscription yesterday, I'm not sure why one works and the other does not, nore where else to check for size limitations to make the new one work. Any help appreciated

[image: Subscriptions]

Comment: _The server response was: 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size_ This is not an SSRS problem, that message is coming from the target SMTP server. Depending on the SMTP server's software quota limits can be set on a per-mailbox as well as a per-domain basis.